# Firefox not displaying web page as its supposed to

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a list of items with prices on a web page I'm building. It all works completely fine in google but not in firefox. The sausage and chips item should be displaying like the ones under it but it doesn't, and I just cant figure it out. Maybe one of you can. Thanks

heres the part of code thats playing up. Heres the full code https://jsfiddle.net/p2L3uxyp/

```
<ul class="menu-items" id="kids-menu-styling">
<li><span>Sausage and Chips</span></li>
<li><span>(Including drink)</span><span>£3.20</span></li>
<li><span>Scampi and Chips</span></li>
<li><span>(Including drink)</span><span>£3.20</span></li>
<li><span>Fish Goujons and Chips</span></li>
<li><span>(Including drink)</span><span>£3.20</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] *in your question*. We shouldn't have to visit a third-party website to see the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a floating problem. Add `overflow: auto` to `.menu-items`, this will fix it.

https://jsfiddle.net/uncf0t0b/1/

Comment: Thanks so much it was driving me crazy. If you don't mind could you explain why this happened and how this fixed it. Just so I know in the future.

Comment: When an element (in your case the ul with class `.menu-items`) contains floated elements, it's always advisable to add `overflow: auto` to it. Although this is the default setting, it makes sure that the floated elements are really "inside" the container (i.e. wrapped by it) and nothing is acting up funny, as in was the case in your situation (which is a bit strange, but I saw that the first `li` had a height of 0px in the browser tools, so I added this).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is, but you might find it more useful to set up the page slightly differently. I've thrown a quick jsfiddle together for you to demonstrate what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/r4yb53dL/1/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="menu-item-title">Sausage and Chips</div>
    <div class="menu-item-details">
      <span class="details">(Including drink)</span>
      <span class="seperator">  ....  </span>
      <span class="price">£3.20</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

By taking advantage of block elements and inline elements in html, you can use minimal css to achieve what you need.

Edit:

Just wanted to add - thank you for cross browser testing! It's such a shame when a site looks great in one browser, but awful in another.

Edit 2:

Sorry - typo!